java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace
Today i tried to install react native and i stucked at this error
* What went wrong:
java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\nadab\carikampus\android\.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-ddd6805c-d842-4428-a232-84b5d498db8e) to immutable location (C:\Users\nadab\carikampus\android\.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a)
> Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\nadab\carikampus\android\.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-ddd6805c-d842-4428-a232-84b5d498db8e) to immutable location (C:\Users\nadab\carikampus\android\.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a)

even though in "npx react-native doctor" everything is okay:
 ✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
 ✓ yarn - Required to install NPM dependencies
 ✓ Metro - Required for bundling the JavaScript code

Android
 ✓ Adb - Required to verify if the android device is attached correctly
 ✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation
 ✓ Gradlew - Build tool required for Android builds
 ✓ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android

Errors:   0
Warnings: 0

please help me guys
I have followed Stack Overflow's recommendation to change Grandle 8.6 to 8.5 and it's still error

If the error is persistent may be a local anti virus system is blocking access while it is scanning the files. Do you use the built-in Windows scanner or a third party one? If you have a Internet flat you can try to delete the .gradle folder and let gradle rebuild it. If even deleting fails you can use Sysinternal Process Explorer to do a handle search for the blocked file-name to reveal which executables prevent deletion/moving it.

Try this following steps.

Delete the .gradle folder inside the android folder
cd into android folder and run ./gradlew clean for windows.
navigate back to root project and run the project

This works for me. If not working please check this link for official work around
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/46210#issuecomment-2315210922
